# String List Serializer

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a table that must be serialize.

its my class, i add table values to it

```
  public class NewCVXml
{
    [XmlArray]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Name")]
    public List<string> FieldFirst { get; set; }
    [XmlArray]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Value")]
    public List<string> FieldSecond { get; set; }
    [XmlArray]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "State")]
    public List<string> FieldThird { get; set; }

}
```

this is value came from ajax (Request.Form)

> {field1=name1&field1=name2&field1=name3&field2=value1&field2=value2&field2=value3&field3=Private&field3=Public&field3=Public}

and this is my c# function that called by ajax (for posting)

```
       string xmlText;
        NewCVXml newCv = new NewCVXml();
        newCv.FieldFirst =  Request.Form.GetValues(0).ToList();
        newCv.FieldSecond = Request.Form.GetValues(1).ToList();
        newCv.FieldThird = Request.Form.GetValues(2).ToList();

        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(newCv.GetType());
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented })
            {

                serializer.Serialize(writer, newCv);
                ms = (MemoryStream)writer.BaseStream;
                xmlText = new UTF8Encoding().GetString(ms.ToArray());
                ms.Dispose();
                return Content(xmlText);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            return Content( "Hata: " + e.Message);

        }
```

and this xml creates

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NewCVXml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <FieldFirst>
    <Name>name1</Name>
    <Name>name2</Name>
    <Name>name3</Name>
  </FieldFirst>
  <FieldSecond>
    <Value>value1</Value>
    <Value>value2</Value>
    <Value>value3</Value>
  </FieldSecond>
  <FieldThird>
    <State>Private</State>
    <State>Public</State>
    <State>Public</State>
  </FieldThird>
</NewCVXml>
```

[image: my table]

But I want something like that xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NewCVXml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Rows>
    <name1 state="Private">value1</name1>
    <name2 state="Public">value2</name2>
    <name3 state="Public">value3</name3>
</Rows>
</NewCVXml>
```

I dont know how I can create like that xml.  I cannot use a class for each row. Because cells of rows are changeable. I mean, it can be name1 or XXX or YYY or ... it depens on user. Everything is dynamic then I think that I need to use a string list and create tagname from list values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You class structure does not serialize to XML in the way you would like using the standard XmlSerializer.  Instead, you could implement custom serialization using IXmlSerializable.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx

```
public class NewCVXml : IXmlSerializable {

    public List<string> FieldFirst { get; set; }
    public List<string> FieldSecond { get; set; }
    public List<string> FieldThird { get; set; }

    public void WriteXml (XmlWriter writer)
    {
        // Custom Serialization Here
    }

    public void ReadXml (XmlReader reader)
    {
        // Custom Deserialization Here
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return(null);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes. I think that is what I really need. Thank you , I will search about custom xml serialization :)

Answer (score 0):

as Robert Graves said, I needed a custom xml serializer. I used code which Robert gave and edit it. It works now, maybe some people will need it then I put it here

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace E_Cv.Functions
{
    public class NewCVXml :IXmlSerializable
    {

        public List<string> FieldFirst { get; set; }
        public List<string> FieldSecond { get; set; }
        public List<string> FieldThird { get; set; }

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {


            for (int i = 0; i < FieldFirst.Count; i++)
            {

                writer.WriteStartElement("Satir");

                writer.WriteAttributeString("AlanIsmi",FieldFirst[i]);
                //writer.WriteString(FieldFirst[i]);    
                writer.WriteAttributeString("AlanTuru", FieldThird[i]);
                writer.WriteString(FieldSecond[i]); 
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }


        }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            // Custom Deserialization Here
        }

        public XmlSchema GetSchema()
        {
            return (null);
        }
    }
}
```